# How to replace items with their indices in a pandas series

Tags: pandas

#### Problem Statement

I have file containing a graph. The file is a csv with two columns, source name and target name. I'd like to generate a file/dataframe with source and target being numerical IDs instead of strings.

I know this can be done in python, with something like

```
node_names = list(set(source_node_names) | set(target_node_names))
names_to_ids = invert(dict(enumerate(node_names)))  
# followed by some sort of replace operation using this dictionary
```

But I'm trying to learn pandas, and felt this would be a good opportunity to do so.

#### Some questions:

- Does it make sense to use a [Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) for this problem? I didn't think so, since each of my nodes is not a category, but my googling was steering me in that direction.
- Right now I have my names in a series. [Series.factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html) seemed promising, but I'm not entirely clear on what the return is, largely because I'm not clear on what a pandas Index is.
- *Meta-question #1*: Is there a good explanation of pandas Index somewhere? I can't find a "pandas Index tutorial" probably in part because pandas has a tutorial called [Indexing and Selecting Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) which I think answers most people's questions, but assumes some knowledge I don't have:

  > The pandas Index class and its subclasses can be viewed as implementing an *ordered multiset*.

  =0
- *Meta-question #2*: Are there any excellent resources for learning pandas?So far I've been doing a lot of googling for docs and stackoverflowing, but I may want to learn pandas properly. Are there large tutorials or books people trust?

#### My best idea so far:

I think I could take my series of node names, somehow explicitly make it a dataframe such that one column is the indices and another is the name, then do two [merges](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with the graph dataframe, once on source and once on target, such that I have source IDs and target IDs, then just hold on to those two fields. It feels to me like there must be a better way than two merges.

#### Some sample data

As requested by @Cleb. Input:

```
# I have                And I want: 
    RNF14   VDR             0   1
    RNF14   SMAD            0   2
    RNF14   UBE2D4          0   3
    RNF14   EIF2B5          0   4
    RNF14   UBE2D2          0   5
    RNF14   SMAD            0   6
    RNF14   UBE2D1          0   7
    RNF14   UBE2D3          0   8
    RNF14   IST1            0   9
    RNF14   EXOSC3          0   10
    RNF14   EXOSC5          0   11
    RNF14   SMURF1          0   12
    RNF14   SMURF2          0   13
```

Obviously this is a trivial case. I have about a million edges in my graph, for maybe 100k nodes.

#### Update #1:

It seems like factorizing might be what I want, but I want to factorize two columns of a dataframe in the same index space, which seems non-obvious.

I've built an index from names to IDs, I just don't know how to replace my original dataframe with the IDs. This would be some kind of "merge" operation I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Could you add some data to play with, including your desired result?

Comment: @Cleb see above

Comment: I guess you are looking for pd.get_dummies()

Comment: Close, but not quite @VaishaliGarg, unless I'm reading the docs page for get_dummies wrong. That builds a matrix, I think, whee I want a list. I think doing get_dummies and then another transform could work though, but alone it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt for [`pd.factorize()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) across columns.

```
df.apply(lambda col: pd.factorize(col)[0]+1)
```

If you want unique ids in each column, you could just unstack first.

```
stacked = df.stack()
pd.DataFrame(stacked.factorize()[0], index=stacked.index).unstack()
```

**Demo**

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(const=['things']*12, 
                           unqs=['foo']*4+['bar']*3+['baz']*5))

>>> df
     const unqs
0   things  foo
1   things  foo
2   things  foo
3   things  foo
4   things  bar
5   things  bar
6   things  bar
7   things  baz
8   things  baz
9   things  baz
10  things  baz
11  things  baz

>>> stacked = df.stack()

>>> pd.DataFrame(stacked.factorize()[0], index=stacked.index).unstack()
       0     
   const unqs
0      0    1
1      0    1
2      0    1
3      0    1
4      0    2
5      0    2
6      0    2
7      0    3
8      0    3
9      0    3
10     0    3
11     0    3
```

Comment: Hi @Mitch! Thanks for answering my question! One issue though: Items in the first column and second column share a namespace (nodes in a graph) and should therefore be in the same ID space. If I'm not mistaken, your code above assigns different ID spaces to the first and second columns.

Comment: @AlexLenail Sorry, I don't follow. What do you want in the first column in my example? You want both columns to have unique ids from one another?

Comment: This works. Thanks Mitch! Follow up question: are there resources I can look at to learn about stacking so I might not need to ask a variant of this question here next time?

Comment: @AlexLenail I'd recommend both [the Pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) (going over all the sections with the code examples) as well as Tom Augspurger's [modern Pandas](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-1.html) blog series for learning.

Comment: Thanks again @Mitch! You've been super helpful!

Comment: @AlexLenail Found a slightly better way if you want a DataFrame representation, see my edit. And you're welcome!

Comment: I now need the inverse of this operation, replacing indices with names. Would you point me in the way of some pandas docs I could look at?